# Identify input text without any entities in IBM Watson Conversation

Tags: nlp, ibm-watson

Is there a way with Watson to identify `input.text`'s that have no entities at all?

I don't need to know anything about the `input.text`, I just need to know if it does or doesn't have an entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out whether any Entity got identified or not, only from the `entities` array from the response. If this array is empty, then no entity got identified from the `input.text`, else some entities got identified.